# Como fazer um condição de negação com instanceof, sem afetar a ordem da precedencia?

Tags: php, if

Espero que a pergunta não parece estranha, mas posso explicar claramente o que quero dizer.
Sei que quanto a verificações, as vezes é necessário tomar cuidado com a questão da precedência dos operadores ou das próprias condições adicionadas num if.

A minha dúvida é: Qual dessas é a melhor maneira de saber que um objeto não é uma instância de uma classe através de `instanceof`

Geralmente, utilizamos para saber se é uma instância.
Assim:

```
if ($object instanceof WallaceMaxters\Timer\Time) {

}
```

Porém, e se eu quiser saber que não é uma instância?

Já pensei em utilizar dessa forma:

`!$object instanceof Timer`

O que quero saber é o seguinte: Ao colocar o `!` sinal de negação em `$object`, corro algum risco de ser avaliado erroneamente a minha condição; ou seja, avaliar um boleano ao invés de um objeto.

Trocando em miudos. Isso...

```
$object = new NotTimer;

!$object instanceof Timer
```

Seria avaliado como isso ...

```
NotTimer(object) instanceof Timer
```

Ou isso?

```
false instanceof Timer
```

## Observação

Já vi frameworks que fazem isso:

```
!($object instanceof Timer)
```

Mas isso é realmente necessário, ou há realmente um problema possível ao gerar uma condição com sinal de negação antes do `instanceof`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você olhar a [tabela de precedência de operadores do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), verá que o `instanceof` tem precedência maior que o `!`. Isso quer dizer que, numa expressão que inclua ambos, o `instanceof` é aplicado antes. Portanto as duas variantes são equivalentes:

```
// Neste caso, a versão sem parênteses:
!$object instanceof Foo

// significa exatamente o mesmo que:
!($object instanceof Foo)
```

A opção de usar ou não os parênteses é de quem escreve o código. Optar pelos parênteses pode ser uma maneira de deixar clara a sua intenção, caso a dúvida sobre precedência surja em quem estiver lendo.

Comment: Falou e disse amigo! Muito bem explicado!